# Strange network behaviour

Tags: networking, svelte, sapper

I was currently using Sapper and I just noticed a strange network behavior. As soon as I reload my page, all files are doubled included.
Is that normal?

Thank you and have a nice day
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because there is a service worker that intercepts the request.

You can find a good explanation about this here: [Service worker sends two requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242899/service-worker-sends-two-requests)