# Why go twice api call in service worker (PWA)?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I implemented a service worker (PWA) in an Angular project. I see in our network panel that all api calls run twice.

I am confused, is it take a more time or save time?

How to stop twice call in service worker?

Please see my attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This should answer your question: [Stack Overflow - Service worker sends two requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242899/service-worker-sends-two-requests)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service worker sends two requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242899/service-worker-sends-two-requests)